# Why Tinymce fails to load second time?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have following code, to render tinymce. It was working perfectly before, but do not know why it suddenly break. First it render tinymce perfectly. Second time it fails to load. Second I found `tinymce.editors.length = 1`, means editor is there.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    paste_as_text: true,
    mode: 'textareas',
    plugins: ['paste link textcolor'],
    force_br_newlines: true,
    paste_remove_spans: true,
    toolbar: "undo redo | bold italic underline forecolor | link unlink",
    menubar: false,
    statusbar: false,
    browser_spellcheck: true,
    forced_root_block: "",
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('init', function() {
            $('#loading_gfx').css('display', 'none'); 
        });

    }
});
```

Solution I found

```
if (tinymce.editors.length > 0) {
    tinymce.execCommand('mceFocus', true, textArea_id );       
    tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor',true, textArea_id);        
    tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor',true, textArea_id);
}
```

But I am not able to get why it suddenly break, I have latest tiny mce version 4.2.3
Anyone know the reason.

Answer (score 8):

remove existing instance before trying to create duplicate:

```
tinymce.remove("#editor");

tinymce.init({ target: document.getElementById('editor') });
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason why its not loading the second time is because you haven't defined the `selector` property to bind to the `textarea` by it's `id` in the `init({})`. The init selector property expects a `#` before the id. While the `execCommand` doesn't expect the `#` before the id.

HTML

```
<form>
    <textarea id='instance1'></textarea>
</form>
```

JS

```
var textArea_id = "instance1";

tinyMCE.init({
    //******bind to textarea 
    selector: "#instance1",
    mode: "textareas",
    paste_as_text: true,
    plugins: ['paste link textcolor'],
    force_br_newlines: true,
    paste_remove_spans: true,
    toolbar: "undo redo | bold italic underline forecolor | link unlink",
    menubar: false,
    statusbar: false,
    browser_spellcheck: true,
    forced_root_block: "",
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('init', function() {
           $('#loading_gfx').css('display', 'none'); 
        });
    }
});

if (tinymce.editors.length > 0) {
    tinymce.execCommand('mceFocus', true, textArea_id );       
    tinymce.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor',true, textArea_id);        
    tinymce.execCommand('mceAddEditor',true, textArea_id);
}
```

Here is a working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PalinDrome555/h4481j4d/)

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, given the solution that works, something loads TinyMCE two times, and the second time causes the error. It would be helpful to see the javascript that loads tinymce, the html of the container element, and the order in which javascripts, especially jQuery and tinyMCE are loaded in your application.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem of the **tinymce** is reinitialize the textarea/div for remove the existing form the area using

```
tinymce.remove();
```

and initialize again using following code

```
tinymce.init({
  selector: "textarea"
});
```

Using tinymce.remove(), it will remove all editors from the existing page. 
If do you want to remove one specific editor from the page, you can pass the ID as a parameter,

```
tinymce.remove('#your_id').
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create the tinymce inside a jQuery dialog for example, make sure you remove the dialog and the tinymce on dialog close. 
Ex:

```
close: function(){
        $('#tinymce-textarea-id').tinymce().remove();
        $('#dialog-id').dialog('destroy');
        $('#dialog-id').remove();
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

For me everything was working fine when I would submit the form but tinymce was not loading second time if I clicked on Cancel button. But when I refreshed the page it was loading properly again so I decided to add location reload method to my Cancel button:

```
$('#edit').on('click', '#fp_cancel', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.colorbox.close(); 
    location.reload(false);
});
```

Now everything is working properly.